# Ferromagnetic vs Paramagnetic

Tags: magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I know a ferromagnetic material (e.g iron) losses its ferromagnetic properties over the Curie temperate. What are the other methods to make iron paramagnetic from its ferromagnetic stage? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Paramagnetism (or even diamagnetism) is related to how the material responds to an applied magnetic field. On the other hand ferromagnetism (analogously, antiferromagnetism) is related to the alignment of the microscopic magnetic moments in the material).

In this sense, if you take a ferromagnet and apply a sufficiently strong magnetic field you should see the arisal of paramegnetic behaviour. This of course **if and only if** the material is also a paramagnet.

Comment: But here, My question is related to the ferromagnetic material. Can a ferromagnetic material, such as iron, lose its ferromagnetic property by other methods except heating over the curie temperature?

Comment: By application of a sufficiently high magnetic field